# Error when npm install private github repository as a dependency

Tags: javascript, git, npm

When I add the private repository to package.json, I get an error when I try to install it with the `npm install` command. I don't get any errors when I run this error with the `yarn install` command.

package.json:

`"repo-name": "git+https://github_pat_***:x-oauth-basic@github.com/company/repo-name.git"`

log:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/username/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneXObG5S/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneXObG5S/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2024-02-22T15_22_06_508Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Add the registry you want to download from in a `.npmrc` file at the root of the project

Comment: `@company:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=github_pat_****`

I added but still same issue.